# python won't execute second condition if elif

Tags: python

i have this on my script

```
for x in test:
    extra_data_list = ast.literal_eval(x['extra_data'][3])
    if extra_data_list.has_key('first_name') == True:
        if extra_data_list['email_address'] == current_user['email']:
            linked.append('Linkedin')
    elif is_google == current_user['email']:
        linked.append('Google Plus')
```

but when i pass linked to my template, i got one result, just 'Linkedin',
even second condition is also true, can you tell me to solve this ?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It seems that you are assuming we know what the rest of the program is. "when i pass linked to my template" - What is your template? What is linked?

Comment: so which part is not executed and should be ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a tab before the elif. It referers to the external if

Answer (score 0):

Because the first if condition is true your code cannot execute the elif!

You can just use a normal if statement:

```
for x in test:
    extra_data_list = ast.literal_eval(x['extra_data'][3])
    if extra_data_list.has_key('first_name') == True:
        if extra_data_list['email_address'] == current_user['email']:
            linked.append('Linkedin')
    if is_google == current_user['email']:
        linked.append('Google Plus')
```